# New Exchange Rate Provider configuration AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have created a new Exchange provider according to the Manual in the Microsoft Page but when I try to import the data's it shows nothing,no errors and doesn't make the import of the data.I try to debug but I get nowhere.
Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Did you perform an incremental CIL build?

Comment: Yes,I performed it

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are referring to the [Creating Exchange Rate Providers for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36047) white paper.

Following the instructions in the white paper, I encountered the following problems:

- The `getExchangeRates` method contains a `try-catch` block that swallows all exceptions silently, including the exceptions from the following problems.
- The `getExchangeRates` method contains a hidden* TODO to replace part of a commented code line with the API key that you receive when you register with Oanda (see chapter "Before you begin" in the white paper or [OANDA Exchange Rates API](http://developer.oanda.com/exchange-rates-api/)). After replacing the part with your API key, the line must be un-commented, of course.
- For the `rateEnumerator` variable in the `getExchangeRates` method, no `moveNext()` is made, which causes the subsequent `current()` call to fail.
- In the last `if` statement in method `readRate`, `exchangeRate` should be replaced with `exchangeDate`.

After resolving these issues and doing an incremental CIL compilation, I was able to import exchange rates.

Regarding debugging: the code of the new exchange rate provider is run in CIL, so you need Visual Studio to debug the code (see [Walkthrough: Using the Debug Properties When Debugging Managed Code (AX 2012)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh129886.aspx)). You can also set a breakpoint in class `SysOperationServiceController`, method `run` and then force the code to execute not in CIL using the "Set Next Statement" function in the debugger to execute the `this.runOperation(false);` statement.

*hidden because it does not appear as a task in the compiler window

Comment: Yes that is the document I used,but another fact is that the service is created by me locally,so I guess I do not need an API,and the read rate method has my own logic.I try to debug in the class, but  the debugger stops at the this.runOperationWithRunAs(),I can not go further.

Comment: If you read my answer carefully, you will notice that this debugging problem is addressed there.

Comment: I solved the issue by not using this paper but by duplicating the class developed for the Russian Bank and adapted it to my service and it works now.